# Trouble with executing code if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate values of a form only if checkbox is unchecked. If it is checked, I will use values added previously. Now the thing is this or any of these code are not working. As I need to validate these values before I redirecting values to another form.

```
var ui=document.getElementById('same_info').value;
    ui.OnChange = valid;
       function valid()
         {var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myform");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("shipping_first_name","alpha_s","please enter your First Name or full name");
frmvalidator.addValidation("shipping_first_name","req","Please enter your First Name");

}
```

2.

```
 if(!document.myform.same_info.checked)

{ alert('infobox  is not checked'); }
```

I am using Javascript  to validate form. Script is fine as it is working perfectly with form elements , whose values are not depending on checking/unchecking of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var ui=document.getElementById('same_info').value;
```

to

```
var ui=document.getElementById('same_info');
```

Also, I'm fairly certain it's `onchange`, not `OnChange` -- Javascript is case sensitive.

```
ui.onchange = valid;
```

Also note that if the user checks it, and unchecks it, it will still have those validation requirements even though it has been unchecked.

Comment: thanks for answering,i did what you advise , but its not working.